# combine columns with different data types to make a single dateTime column in pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have imported data from some source that has date in datatype class 'object' and hour in integer and looks something like:

```
Date           Hour    Val
2019-01-01  1   0
2019-01-01  2   0
2019-01-01  3   0
2019-01-01  4   0
2019-01-01  5   0
2019-01-01  6   0
2019-01-01  7   0
2019-01-01  8   0
```

I need a single column that has the date-time in a column that looks like this:

```
DATETIME
2019-01-01 01:00:00
2019-01-01 02:00:00
2019-01-01 03:00:00
2019-01-01 04:00:00
2019-01-01 05:00:00
2019-01-01 06:00:00
2019-01-01 07:00:00
2019-01-01 08:00:00
```

I tried to convert the date column to dateTime format using

```
pd.datetime(df.Date)
```

and then using

```
df.Date.dt.hour = df.Hour
```

I get the error

> ValueError: modifications to a property of a datetimelike object are not supported. Change values on the original.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas.to_datetime&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB811GB811&oq=pandas.to_datetime&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2765j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
# if needed
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Datetime'] = df['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'], unit='H')
```

[out]

```
        Date  Hour  Val            Datetime
0 2019-01-01     1    0 2019-01-01 01:00:00
1 2019-01-01     2    0 2019-01-01 02:00:00
2 2019-01-01     3    0 2019-01-01 03:00:00
3 2019-01-01     4    0 2019-01-01 04:00:00
4 2019-01-01     5    0 2019-01-01 05:00:00
5 2019-01-01     6    0 2019-01-01 06:00:00
6 2019-01-01     7    0 2019-01-01 07:00:00
7 2019-01-01     8    0 2019-01-01 08:00:00
```

---

Since you asked for a method combining the columns and using a single `pd.to_datetime` call, you could do:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' +
                                 df['Hour'].astype(str)),
                                 format='%Y-%m-%d %I')
```

Comment: Is there a way to use just to_datetime by modifying my original data? like combining the date and hour column first and then using a single to_datetime?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you coud do `pd.to_datetime((df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Hour'].astype(str)), format='%Y-%m-%d %I')`, but it's not very pythonic imho